# Weird numbers appears in the output while looping

Tags: c

I make a program to convert decimal numbers to binary. The problem is why looping on case 2 and so on keep outputting weird number.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int b;
    int p;
    int rem[100];
    
    scanf("%d", &b);
    
    for(int z = 0; z < b; z++){
        scanf("%d", &p);
    
        int a = 0;
        while(p > 0){
            rem[a] = p[z] % 2;
            p[z] /= 2;
            a++;
        }
        
        printf("Case #%d: ", z+1);
        
        for(int x = a - 1; a >= 0; a--){
            printf("%d", rem[a]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    
    return 0;
}
```

I think the last number in that weird number is the binary. How can I remove that weird number so the output is just the binary value?

Comment: `p` isn't an array, so `p[z]` makes no sense and it doesn't compile.

Comment: `for(int x = a - 1` is a good start for that loop, perhaps you want to use `x` a bit more, like everywhere you're using `a` now inside that loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many mistakes first remove the for loop its not needed and p isn't array
and also taking input from scanf twice. and p is not needed.

```
// C Code to convert Decimal number into Binary

#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int b;
    int rem[100]; // array to store binary number

scanf("%d", &b);//Enter the number you want to convert


    int a = 0; // counter for binary array
    while(b > 0){
          // storing remainder in binary array
        rem[a] = b % 2;
        b /= 2;
        a++;
    }
    
   // printf("Case #%d: ", b+1);
    // printing binary array in reverse order
    for(int x = a - 1; x >= 0; x--){
        printf("%d", rem[x]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the question, the first `scanf()` is used to enter the number of numbers to be converted.  However, it would be better to simply loop until EOF (or an error).  Your code only converts a single number; the original code loops and converts many numbers.